# Установка курсора в стилях по умолчанию элемента или в элементе: hover?

Tags: html, css3

Существует ли какая-либо практическая разница между  двумя способами задания курсора?

```
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

И:

```
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

В [документах MDN указано](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor), что:

> Свойство `CSS` курсора определяет, какой курсор мыши будет
>   отображаться, когда указатель её находится над элементом.

Итак, есть ли какая-то реальная разница? Должны ли быть один способ предпочтительными по сравнению с другими, или они взаимозаменяемы?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51357279/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Да, есть разница, первый способ определяется при загрузке `CSS`, а вторая способ  только на `:hover`.
Визуально мы не видим разницы, но если вы используете изображение в качестве курсора, то вы можете иметь небольшую задержку, если вы определяете курсор при наведении, поскольку вам нужно ждать загрузки изображения.

```css
button:hover {
  cursor:url(https://picsum.photos/90/90?image=1069) 5 5, help;
}
```

```html
<button>wait for loading</button>
```

Во втором примере изображение будет загружено перед наведением курсора (вы можете проверить вкладку сети в своем браузере, чтобы заметить это):

```css
button {
  cursor:url(https://picsum.photos/90/90?image=1062) 5 5, help;
}
```

```html
<button>no need to wait for loading</button>
```

Поэтому лучше использовать второй способ, чтобы избежать любой задержки и при необходимости подготовить курсор.

Comment: второй абзац не переведен